# Can not set current item of select-tag WITH bound background-color in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind the background-color to the current item of a selected-tag.

I thought it must work because I am really assigning the color reference object to the currentColorDefinitin variable which is bound to ngModel.

But it does not work, why?

**HTML**

```
<select style="width:150px;" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentColorDefinition">
    <option [style.background-color]="item.backgroundcolor" *ngFor="let item of colorDefinitions" [ngValue]="item">
    </option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
colorDefinitions: Color[] = [
new Color("#000000", "#FFFFFF"), // black
new Color("#FF0000", "#FFFFFF"), // yellow
];
currentColorDefinition: Color;
this.currentColorDefinition = this.colorDefinitions[0];
```

Comment: is anything selected?

Comment: This is what I mean. No color is visible as selected. But of course the colorDefinitions Array is bound correctly and visible when I open/click the dropdown.

Comment: it shows you empty value which is set to option.

Comment: @RomanC Can you rephrase your statement please I am not sure what it means :-)

Comment: The options are all empty, and you can't see the option which was selected, you can only get the selected value. Saying it doesn't work is not true because if you expect the DOM you should find the *selected* option.

Comment: The question isn't accurate enough. I think that he wants to have a custom background-color for the selected option!

Comment: @SébastienTemprado Right! I want to have a custom background-color for the selected option!

Comment: Hope this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235863/get-value-from-selected-dropdown-list-in-angular-2/43235942?noredirect=1#comment73544490_43235942) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked for me using bootstrap 4. It fits nice to the rest of my design because right to this dropdown I have another button, now I can wrap both buttons with a button-group :-)

```
<div ngbDropdown>
    <button   [style.background-color]="currentColorDefinition.backgroundcolor" class="btn" id="dropdownMenu1"
        ngbDropdownToggle>Farbe</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <button style="height:20px;" name="colorer" (click)="setColor(item)" 
        class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of colorDefinitions" [value]="item"  [style.background-color]="item.backgroundcolor">{{item.foregroundcolor}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work only with a primitive value  :

Model:

```
export class Color {
    first: string;
    second: string;

    constructor(f : string, s : string) {
        this.first=f;
        this.second =s;
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="currentColorDefinition.first">
    <option *ngFor="let item of colorDefinitions"
            [selected]="currentColorDefinition.first == item.first ? true : null"
            [value]="item.first" 
            [style.background-color]="item.first">
            {{item.first}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is odd, because I already used the select-tag with complex object before and there the currentItem worked!

Comment: Your code does NOT work! The selected item has no color!

Comment: there was a mistake. I have replaced `[style.background-color]="item.backgroundcolor"` by `[style.background-color]="item.first"`. But you should have noticed that the option was selected

Comment: When I copy your code and replace the property 'first' with my property 'backgroundcolor' the selected item has NO background color! Please make me a screenshot! On what browser has your current item a set background color?

Comment: You were right : you can use a complex object with ngValue like you have done. It's simpler like that.

Comment: Its simpler like that??? But its not working, sorry I dont get your statement. In the meanwhile I made it working with a bootstrap dropdown button because I anyway use bootstrap...

Comment: it's simpler to use ngValue thant [value] and [selected]

Comment: The [ngValue] binding did not help and the [value] never worked too! Now I use a Bootstrap 4 solution as I already use bootstrap! It could work with this fix: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13349 , but still I prefer now bootstrap solution :-)