# Get value from selected dropdown list in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a database table with two attributes (Name_of_Game and Type_of_Game). I have been to extract the **Name_of_Game** into a select dropdown list. But this is what i want to do now. After selecting the game from the dropdown list, how can the **type** input be set to the game's respective type automatically?

**Example**

Game
  Lord of the Rings

Type

Adventure

After selecting Lord of the rings from the dropdown list, the type input box should be automatically set to Adventure.

```
    //Component 

    export class ChatComponent{

         Game : Games [];
         constructor(private http:HttpService){

         // list all games into the dropdown list
            this.http.listgames()
            .subscribe(data => {

                this.Games = data;
    })

    }

   //html

            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="game"  [(ngModel)]="game.name" required>
                <option *ngFor="let games of Games" [ngValue]="games" > {{games.name}} </option>


            </select>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="type">Type:</label>
                <input type="type" class="form-control" name="type"   [(ngModel)]="game.type">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please look at the naming convention, I have changed names in my example a bit, to more reflect the lower/uppercase we usually use ;)

You are on the right track for using `[ngValue]`. Have your name bind the whole object, which we can then use in the type, to show the corresponding type. So let's create a variable to which we will store the chosen game when user chooses a name from the drop down list here let's call it `selectedGame`:

Component:

```html
selectedGame: Object = {};
```

Template:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGame" required>
  <option *ngFor="let game of games" [ngValue]="game">{{game.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now we have bound the whole object to `selectedGame`, so the input field will reflect that we make a change, as we use `selectedGame.type` as two way-binding for the input field. So your template would look like this:

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGame" required>
   <option *ngFor="let game of games" [ngValue]="game" > {{game.name}} </option>
</select>
<label>Type:</label>
<input type="type"name="type" [(ngModel)]="selectedGame.type">
```

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdkniAYmu1ADKPXdQK2J?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You should be using name property as you are pointing to the name in the [(ngModel)] you should use the same property to bind to the `ngValue` as belew

```
<select class="form-control" name="game"  [(ngModel)]="game.name" required>
                <option *ngFor="let games of Games" [ngValue]="games.name" > {{games.name}} </option>
</select>
```

Update : if you want the type then you should be doing as below

```
<select class="form-control" name="game" (change)="valueChange()" [(ngModel)]="game" required>
                <option *ngFor="let games of Games" [ngValue]="games" > {{games.name}} </option>
</select>
```

Modify your textbox to contain some name as model

```
<input type="type" class="form-control" name="type"   [(ngModel)]="someName">
```

You method looks like

```
valueChange(games){
    this.someName=this.game.type;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xbm5nrYViNwEhMVG2XWr?p=preview)**

Comment: `this.someName=this.game.type;`  when i console log (this.game.type). it is undefined. Could that be where the error is from?

Comment: because it is undefined at the component init

Comment: what is that you are doing in your code. update the one which you tried. or reach me in fb @ aravind2109 and I can work in teamviewer for you

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 4 you can do:

```
(change)="MyMethod($event.target.value)"
```

to pass the selected value to a Typescript method.