# <select> tag model value not working

Tags: html, angular

I am new to angular2 so trying to understand many things here. I have a select box for which I need the value to be passed to method on change (this is being tried for autocomplete). But when I use [(ngModel)], the bind is not working and is throwing an error. Would anybody know how to do this?

```
<select class="form-control" name="SearchBy" [(ngModel)]="SearchFor" (change)="changeSearchFor(SearchFor)">
                        <option value="1">Name</option>
                        <option value="2">ID</option>
                        <option value="3">SID</option>
                        <option value="4">Cost Center</option>
                        <option value="5">Manager ID</option>
                        <option value="6">Unit</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Can you show your component and the error

Comment: Are you getting error in `SearchFor`?

Comment: " is throwing an error" please post the full and exact error message

Comment: If you use `ngModel` it's a bad idea to use `(change)="..."`. Use instead `(ngModelChange)="changeSearchFor(SearchFor)"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, so I should still use the [ngModel] for this right?

Comment: @Aneez can you please provide the component and the stack trace for ehich it is throwing error

Comment: @Aneez where's the error message?

Comment: when you are using `ngModel` you should have `ngValue` in the options. Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235863/get-value-from-selected-dropdown-list-in-angular-2/43235942#43235942)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from selected dropdown list in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235863/get-value-from-selected-dropdown-list-in-angular-2)

Comment: Actually my above comment isn't entirely correct. You should use `(ngModelChange)="changeSearchFor($event)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ngModel` use `ngModelChange` to get notified about changes. `(change)="..."` is fired before `SearchFor` is updated by `ngModel` updated

```
<select class="form-control" name="SearchBy" [(ngModel)]="SearchFor" (ngModelChange)="changeSearchFor($event)">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SL8CRtzqPzNR3tUsPxYB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error using the ngModel directive, probably is due to you've not imported FormsModule, as the syntax seems correct to me. 
You need these lines in the module:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      FormsModule
    ]
})
```

Also you don't need to pass SeachFor as a parameters as it is a variable that you're already linking in your typescript.

PD: If you're going to include autocomplete, have you considered defining a model driven form? This way you can subscribe to the form valueChanges observable and apply reactive programming to it, as it is explained in this link:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get a value in your function, then you can do it without `ngModel`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="SearchBy" (change)="changeSearchFor($event.target.value)">
  <option value="1">Name</option>
  <option value="2">WWID</option>
  <option value="3">IDSID</option>
  <option value="4">Cost Center</option>
  <option value="5">Manager WWID</option>
  <option value="6">Organisational Unit</option>
</select>
```

if you do use `ngModel`, make sure to import and add to `@NgModule`'s imports array FormsModule:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PGeipOAz5kKpxO5HdTc8?p=preview